# Is there a simple way to remove duplicate values in certain cells of a dataframe column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column with city locations and some of the cells have the same value (city) twice within each cell. I was wondering how to get rid of one of the values. eg. Instead of it saying Dublin Dublin below it will only say Dublin once.

I have tried `df['city'].apply(set)` but it doesn't give me what I am looking for.

Any advice much appreciated. Please see the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split each item by   (space) and convert each list of split strings to a `set` (which is deduplicated, but not sorted), and then re-join:

```
df['city'] = df['city'].str.split().apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).drop_duplicates().tolist()).str.join(' ')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
             city
0  Los Angeles CA
1            none
2          London
3          Dublin
```

Comment: That solves the problem thanks however I have just remembered it will become an un ordered set. Is there anyway to preserve the non duplicated values eg. keeping it as los Angeles CA instead of unordering it as los CA Angeles?

Comment: Wow, very very surprised I didn't see that! Yes, there probably is. Let me see...

Comment: There we go. It's a bit longer, but it should preserve the sort order for you.

Comment: @Andrewoca you're welcome! Actually, I just made it quite a bit shorter ;)

Comment: Also, by the way, if you don't mind my asking, what are those awesome-looking cars in your profile picture? They're pretty neat, and *just yesterday* I saw a really cool sportscar I'd never before and it looked really similar...

Comment: They are just from a car show! not mine unfortunately, I wish maybe some day ha

Comment: Yeah...well, keep doing data science & ML for a few years.... ;)